# Vue 3 inject with props = undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

When I receive a "bill" object through a prop from another component, I want to transfer this "bill" to a completely different component. But it gives me an error:
"[Vue warn]: injection "bill" not found."

**Home.vue**

```
    <div v-if="billData.length > 0">
      <Bill v-for="(bill, index) in billData" :bill="bill" :key="index" />
    </div>
```

Here I am passing object to component.

**Bill.vue**

```
<script setup>
import { defineProps, provide, computed } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  bill: Object,
});

provide('bill', props.bill);
</script>
```

In this component, I get this object and make a provide. Object has properties.
[This is a component with props (bill)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iSte.jpg)

After clicking on the component (bill) I get the error:
[Vue warn: injection "bill" not found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ELaA.jpg)

**BillView.vue**

```
<script setup>
import { inject, watchEffect } from 'vue';

const bill = inject('bill');
</script>
```

In this component, I inject, after which I get undefined if output in a template or in the console.log.

I watched videos of similar actions. But for some reason I have a problem:
[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIrgiP3Nn_U&ab_channel=MichaelHoffmann)

I have tried different solutions. I even found a video with the same actions, but for some reason it doesn't work for me...

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unclear how these comps are related.